# MongoDB increment/decrement or upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to decrement a field in a document and set a default value  if it does not exist. My query below:

```
 usersCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
    {_id: id},
    {
        $inc: {quota: -1},
        $setOnInsert: {quota: 100}
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
        returnOriginal: false
    }
)
```

But this query gives the following error:

> Updating the path 'quota' would create a conflict at 'quota'

If I don't use the `$setOnInsert: {quota: 100}` then it works but starts decrementing from 0 which I don't want. My goal is to set a default value (100) in this case and decrement on each query. 
Is this possible in 1 query ? I have searched around but didn't find something that could help.

Comment: The docs conveniently avoid this situation...

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Are you saying it is not possible and discouraged ?

Comment: The basic premise is don't do it. Instead you really should separate the operations. A `bulkWrite()` is the most viable fix: `usersCollection.bulkWrite([{ updateOne: { filter: { _id: id }, update: { $inc: { quota: -1 } } }},{ updateOne: { filter: { _id: id }, update: { $setOnInsert: { quota: 100 }, upsert: true } }}])`. So basically **two** statements, where only the **second** attempts the *upsert* and the first only attempts to *modify*.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe this is possible in a single query, as it contains an atomic operation (`$inc`) and contains two potential operations on the same field. (This would explain the 'quota' error message.)

You could use two different queries with the `$exists` operator to determine how the `quota` field should